# Python 3.x - determining when a loop stops with two variables?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I want a loop to continue, an only stop the moment one of the variables reaches a value of 0, but I'm having troubles doing so. I thought a while loop would be perfect for this, but the best I have come up with thus far is:

```
    import random
    min = 1
    max = 6
    number = 10
    number2 = 20
    while number > 0 or number2 > 0:
            number = number - random.randint(min, max)
            number2 = number2 - random.randint(min, max)
            print(number)
            print(number2)
```

I mean, there is a possibility in this structure that 'number2' will get really good rolls, and reach 0 before 'number.' but it is unlikely. Yet the while loop always stops ONLY when 'number2' reaches 0 or under.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `and` operator, not the `or` operator, for the two conditions for your `while` loop, since you want *both* of them to be satisfied in order for the loop to continue.

```
number = 10
number2 = 20
while number > 0 and number2 > 0:
    number = number - 1
    number2 = number2 - 1
    print(number)
```

This outputs:

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: Huh...yea, that clicks, and makes sense now. Thanks